# hover() not working like intended

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list element like below, I'm trying to just target the image element with jQuery. What is happening is it moves both the `span` element and the `img` up by 15 pixels instead of just the image.

However if I move the `span` element before the `img` in the HTML it will target the image element correctly. Why is this happening?

```
<ul class="mainnav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="circles"><img src="/bootstrap_a/img/web_icon/blog_i.png"></div>
            <span>Blog</span>
        </a>                        
    </li>
<ul>
```

```js
$(".mainnav li a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({  marginTop: "-15px" }, 250); 
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 250); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing much of anything, here is a relatively dirty fix for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/rDQkS/

Bottom margin is animated the same amount to push the span away, making it look like only the image is moving.

```
$(".mainnav li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('img').stop().animate({  marginTop: "-15px", marginBottom: "15px" }, 250); 
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('img').stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px", marginBottom: "0px" }, 250); 
  }
);​
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you havent closed `<img>` tag .so make sure you close it.

```
$(".mainnav li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('div img').stop().animate({  marginTop: "-15px" }, 250); 
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('div img').stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 250); 
  }
 );
```

Comment: What the OP originally had was fine, as he was traversing using `find()` to get to the `img` element from the `a` being hovered. You've actually broken it more.